# How do I fetch all the price from this url using Beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried all the methods but unable to fetch the price from this particular website. I am getting None as the output.

```
import bs4
import requests
u = 'https://skinport.com/market?cat=Knife&item=Doppler&type=M9+Bayonet&sort=price&order=asc'
r = requests.get(u)
c = r.content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
price = soup.findall("div", {"class": "Tooltip-link"})
print(price)
```

Comment: Have you inspected the contents of `c` to ensure that the elements you're seeking are present there?

Comment: There are no `<span>` tags with that class.  There are a bunch of `<div>` tags, but no `<span>s`.

Comment: I have replaced the <span> to <div> and I want to fetch all the <div> section with class `Tooltip-link` @TimRoberts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This prints the divs you want.  Note that the API is `find_all`, not `findall`.

```
c = r.content.decode('utf-8')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
price = soup.find_all( 'div', {"class": "Tooltip-link"})
print(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no elements like that, as they don't exist in the HTML when you first download the page. They are downloaded asynchronously via [this](https://skinport.com/api/browse/730?cat=Knife&item=Doppler&type=M9+Bayonet&sort=price&order=asc) API request. Instead, you could directly download the JSON data from the API request and parse it using JSON, like so:

```py
from json import loads
from requests import get

data = loads(
    get("https://skinport.com/api/browse/730?cat=Knife&item=Doppler&type=M9+Bayonet&sort=price&order=asc").text
)
```